# How to get session ID from URL after login with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, request

So I have a login page without session ID the URL is as an example this https://tima.tima.com/ the username and password fields look like this

When I log in normally, I get a session ID that I need to log in to all pages of the website. This URL looks like this

https://tima.tima.com/?session=lk45g3vzwy1strn3kn26eow5ncxjfbxm13jebfgp41johtgr

Can anyone help or explain this to me?

I have currently tried it with request but I am too inexperienced or don't see the problem why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The question seems kind of confusing, but I hope I understood your core interest. Let me try to break it down:
A Session ID will normally not be passed as argument within an URL, but via "Cookies".

### Example

You enter a website, which sells graphic cards and includes a filterable product list. Your Session ID is `session_id_123` *(we will explain this later)*.
In the filter menu, you enter that the `maximum_price` should be `500€` and the manufacturer should be either `'foo'` or `'bar'` - and hit the "Save Filters" functionality.
Temporarily, you go to another section (with other URL) of the website, and then come back to the product page. Per default, the browser still renders the filtered
product list per your above criteria - but how?

### Server Side Cookies

When an user/client enters a website, the server assigns an unique identifier to the session of the client and sends this to his browser via cookie. The "session data" will be stored on the server side, referenced with this unique identifier. This enables the server to pick up this user specific data folowing his request.
Above concept is called "Server Side Cookies", because the data is stored on the server. Data can be stored on the server in many different ways - via local system, via a relational DB (like SQLite), via a non relational DB, like a memory DB (like redis), ...

Whereever it is stored, the server stores YOUR preferred filter, referenced by your session, with values somehow like this:

`{session_id_123: {'product_table_filter': {maximum_price: 500, manufacturer: [foo, bar]}}}`.

The cookie in your browser will look as follows: `{session: session_id_123}`.

Once again, the server will send YOUR unique session ID to your browser as Cookie after entering the page, from where it will be picked up for future uses.

*Obviously, preferenced can also be stored over the life time of a session, when the user is logged in. This is typically not done via Cookies though.*

### Client Side Cookies

For unsensitive data, one can also use "Client side Cookies", which transfer the desired data directly within the cookie, from where it can be accessed by server and client. In above example, the server would directly send your filter information to your browser as cookie, from where it will be picked up for subsequent requests. The cookie in your browser will look as follows: `{session_id_123: {'product_table_filter': {maximum_price: 500, manufacturer: [foo, bar]}}}`

Back to the original question - the setup passing the session ID via URL seems questionable. However, it might serve the same purpose as explained in the "Server Site Cookies" section explained above - to tell the server which stored data on the server belongs to the session of the requesting client.

Answer (score 0):

No I found the bug myself some websites create SessionIDs with Javascript and so it doesn't work via request and you have to use Selenium